# Two tables Select Inner Join with order by and where and limit clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, inner-join

So i have this two tables:

```
socc_matches:

`mc_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`mc_analystid` int NOT NULL,
`mc_teamid` int NOT NULL, 
`mc_date` date NOT NULL,
`mc_hometeam` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`mc_awayteam` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`mc_shots` tinyint(40)

socc_shots:

`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`idmatch` int NOT NULL,
`idplayer` int,
`playername` varchar(60)
```

**I want to get all the rows from socc_shots where idmatch is equal to the LAST 3 mc_id from table socc_matches order by date**

Note: idmatch is Foreign Key of mc_id

I've tried this query:

```
$conn = connection ();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM socc_shots INNER JOIN socc_matches ON socc_matches.mc_id = socc_shots.idmatch WHERE socc_matches.mc_id = socc_shots.idmatch  ORDER BY socc_matches.mc_date desc LIMIT 3');

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    }

   $r = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But is not retrieving the data that i want (the query is wrong)

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge ok im gonna do that

Comment: You seem to have a table without a field in your where clause `WHERE socc_matches.mc_teamid = socc_shots ORDER` should `socc_shots` have a field name after it?

Comment: On a sidenote: Your names make it difficult to understand the query. `mc_id` sounds like an ID of a table called `mc`. Is this the case? What is an `mc`? `idmatch` seems to be the ID of a table called `match` or `matches`, but why without an underscore and `id` at the beginning, whereas in `mc_id` the `id` comes at the end? Two different classes of IDs? And `mc_teamid` is the ID of a table called `mc_team` then? So an `mc`, whatever this is, has teams?

Comment: This is the answer for the section in bold: SELECT * FROM socc_shots WHERE idmatch in (SELECT mc_id FROM socc_matches WHERE mc_teamid = 1 ORDER BY mc_date desc LIMIT 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid: `FROM socc_matches.mc_id, socc_shots.idmatch FROM socc_matches`

And this is incomplete: `WHERE socc_matches.mc_teamid = socc_shots`

Corrected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM socc_matches 
INNER JOIN socc_shots ON socc_matches.mc_id = socc_shots.idmatch 
WHERE socc_matches.mc_teamid = socc_shots.mc_teamid
ORDER BY socc_matches.mc_date desc
LIMIT 3
```

(Replace `socc_shots.mc_teamid` with whatever that column is called in that table. Or with some value for that matter, e.g. `WHERE socc_matches.mc_teamid = 123`.)